# Ошибка Build Server TFS: Unable to determine the location of vstest.console.exe

Tags: сервер, юнит-тесты, build, tfs, windows-server-2012

Имеется сервер Windows Server 2012 R2, на котором установлен Team Foundation Server 2015 (версии 15.112.26307.0). На сервере работает Hosted Agent в качестве службы, который выполняет восстановление NuGet-пакетов, сборку и тестирование проектов. На каждый Check-In проекта - выполняется сборка, по ночам выполняются тесты, о результатах которых можно узнать утром.

Начну по порядку:

1. Ранее был Team Foundation Server 2013, он был обновлен до 2015.
2. Был обновлен и Hosted Agent под новый TFS (vsts-agent-win7-x64-2.112.0).
3. Была обновлена версия NuGet.exe с 2.8 до 3.5, чтобы восстановление NuGet-пакетов могло выполняться (этого требовал новый Hosted Agent).

До обновления Hosted Agent-а ночное тестирование работало, после обновления, упало восстановление NuGet-пакетов и тестирование. Восстановление NuGet-пакетов было решено с помощью обновления версия NuGet.exe, а вот тесты валят ошибку во время выполнения, лог:

> Preparing task execution handler. Executing the powershell script:
>   C:\agent_work_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\1.0.84\VSTest.ps1
>   [warning]'##vso[task.logissue type=error;code=' contains logging command keyword '##vso', but it's not a legal command. Please
>   reference documentaion to fix any potentially syntax error
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
>   vso[task.logissue type=error;code= Unable to determine the location of vstest.console.exe ;TaskName=VSTest]
>   [warning]No results found to publish.
>   [error]System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Unable to determine the location of vstest.console.exe --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to determine the location of
>   vstest.console.exe
>   [error]LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.exe completed with return code: -1.

Скриншот лога:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В скрипте VSTest.ps1 лежат стандартные команды, которые руками не редактировались, то есть ранее все работало хорошо, но в новом агенте что-то идет не так. По предложенной ссылке из лога [Task Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) не ясно, что нужно делать. Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой и как ее решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заходим в настройки определения сборки, переходим к пункту <kbd>Visual Studio Test</kbd>:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого меняем версию настроек тестов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оставшиеся настройки можно оставить без изменений, после этого тесты снова работают.